# Resizing a div according to height and width

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resize a div according to the height and width of the browser. The div is supposed to be empty at the beginning and should always mantain a width of 100% and a height of 50% using ONLY javascript.

Here's the code, in this case I used screen.availHeight and screen.availWidth which is fine only in full screen mode.

```js
/* pw stand for width percentage
  ph for height percentage */

var adaptToScreen = function(el,pw,ph){


var screenW = screen.availWidth;
var screenH = screen.availHeight;

var w = screenW*(pw/100);
var h = screenH*(ph/100);


el.style.height=h+"px";
el.style.width=w+"px";

};

adaptToScreen(toDoList,100,50);
```

```html
  <div id="to-do"></div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use CSS? Simple as `width: 100%; height: 50%;`

Comment: because the div at the beginning is empty. I've already tried it doesn't work, I could use pixels as a unit but then I'd have different outcomes on more devices.

Comment: to use CSS you need to set height and position property of HTML and BODY element.
set `position: relative; height: 100%;` for both html and body tags. it'll work

Comment: why not use `window.innerWidth;` and `window.innerHeight;` instead screen... those are browsers, let say` available dimesions.

Comment: Using height percentages will work. You are likely missing a `body { height 100%: }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/akashkanojia/do1fxz8n/)
I've used window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to get height and width of view area.
if you want to use clientWidth and clientHeight you need to set height of HTML and BODY element to 100% so that they consume full height of viewport and 50% height can be calculated from that.

```js
/* pw stand for width percentage
ph for haight percentage */

var adaptToScreen = function(el,pw,ph){

    //var screenW = document.body.clientWidth;
    //var screenH = document.body.clientHeight;
    var screenW = window.innerWidth;
    var screenH = window.innerHeight;

    var w = screenW*(pw/100);
    var h = screenH*(ph/100);


    el.style.height=h+"px";
    el.style.width=w+"px";

};
var toDoList = document.getElementById('to-do');
adaptToScreen(toDoList,100,50);
```

```html
  <div id="to-do"></div>
```

Comment: i've tried to window.innerHeight but it outputs the same result, I start in full sceen mode then when I make the browser smaller the width and height of the div remain as if the browser were still in full screen mode

Comment: for that you need to add a resize handler like this
`window.onresize = function(event){
    adaptToScreen(toDoList, 100, 50);
};`

Answer (score 1):

The use of JS in this case is redundant. It can be accomplished with the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#to-do {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

adaptToScreen(document.getElementById('to-do'),100,50);

Comment: Is that a native JS function? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: I didn't include the document.getElementById('to-do'); in my post but I wrote it in the original code on my computer

Comment: adaptToScreen is the function in the question if that's what you're asking about